# Automatic \noindent on the first paragraph of each theorem environment

Tags: indentation, theorems

I am currently putting a `\noindent` before the first paragraph of each theorem, proof, etc. in my `memoir` document.  Is there any way to have `memoir` do this automatically?

For example, is there any way to make this MWE more concise?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\noindent This is my introduction.

This is the next paragraph of the introduction, which should be indented.

\begin{thm} (Theorem Name)

\noindent This is my theorem.
Note that I do want the ``(Theorem Name)'' to appear on the same line as where it says \textbf{Theorem 0.1}.

This is the next paragraph of the theorem, which should be indented.

\end{thm}

\noindent Here is a note about the theorem.

\begin{proof}

\noindent This proof has no name.

This is the next paragraph of the proof, which should be indented.

\end{proof}

\noindent This is my conclusion.

The end.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see neither sections nor any other heading level in your example.

Comment: I think I mean "environment" rather than "section"; I'll edit the question title accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Does removing the empty lines get rid of the problem?

Comment: No, because then the words "This is my theorem" appear on the same line as the "(Theorem Name)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To typeset the name of a certain theorem, use the optional argument of the theorem's environment, e.g., `\begin{thm}[Theorem Name]`. In my example, I use the `thmtools` package to conveniently define a new style.

To suppress indentation in the first paragraph after a theorem, one may patch the commands `\@endtheorem` and `\endproof` (using the `etoolbox` package) and then use `%` (the comment sign) in the text body. (EDIT: For details about `amsthm`s implementation of theorems, see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36835/510) to [How to prevent paragraph breaks after theorem environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/how-to-prevent-paragraph-breaks-after-theorem-environments))

The `\noindent` in your example's first paragraph would be superfluous if it was preceded by a sectioning command like `\chapter` or `\section`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\@endpefalse}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endproof}{\@endpefalse}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[within=chapter,spaceabove=\topsep,notefont=\normalfont\itshape,
    bodyfont=\itshape,postheadspace=\newline]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=Theorem]{thm}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is my introduction.

This is the next paragraph of the introduction, which should be indented.

\begin{thm}[Theorem Name]
This is my theorem. Note that I do want the ``(Theorem Name)'' to appear on the same
    line as where it says \textbf{Theorem 0.1}.

This is the next paragraph of the theorem, which should be indented.
\end{thm}
% <-- Supresses indentation of following paragraph
Here is a note about the theorem.

\begin{proof}
This proof has no name.

This is the next paragraph of the proof, which should be indented.
\end{proof}
% <-- Supresses indentation of following paragraph
This is my conclusion.

The end.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a theorem style for that:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}% name
  {9pt}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {9pt}%      Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
```

Then the input

```
\begin{thm}[Theorem Name]
This is my theorem.
Note that I do want the ``(Theorem Name)'' to appear on the
same line as where it says \textbf{Theorem 0.1}.

This is the next paragraph of the theorem, which should be indented.
\end{thm}
```

will do what you're looking for.

To get "Proof" on a line by itself you can patch the `proof` environment

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\ignorespaces}{\mbox{}\\\ignorespaces}{}{}
```

If you've not the `xpatch` package, then the more convolute

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname
  {\ignorespaces}{\mbox{}\\\ignorespaces}{}{}
```

is needed.

For the text after a theorem or a proof you need a `\noindent`, but I think it's bad style; it's also bad style to leave "Proof" on a line by itself.