# Indenting paragraphs within a custom theorem environment

Tags: macros, environments, indentation, amsthm

**Issue:** In my custom theorem environment I would like the beginning line of a new paragraph within the theorem environment to immediately follow the line above it and also be indented:

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{fctaylor}% name
  {\topsep}%      Space above
  {\topsep}%      Space below
  {\normalfont}%         Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {\makethmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\newlength\fctaylortheoremindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\fctaylortheoremindent{3em}} % <- customize here
\newlength\fctaylorlabelsep
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\fctaylorlabelsep{1em}} % <- customize here

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makethmhead}[3]{%
  \gdef\thisthmhead{%
    \makebox[\fctaylortheoremindent][l]{\bfseries#2}%
    {\bfseries#1}%
    \@ifnotempty{#3}{ (#3)}%
    \hspace{\fctaylorlabelsep}%
    \phantomsection%%% THIS LINE ADDED
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{fctayloritemize}
 {\list{}{%
    \leftmargin=\fctaylortheoremindent
    \labelwidth=\dimexpr\fctaylortheoremindent-\labelsep\relax
    \itemindent=0pt
  }}
 {\endlist}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newfctaylortheorem}{smomo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\newtheorem*{fctaylor@#2}{#4}}
   {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
     {\IfNoValueTF{#5}
       {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}{#4}}
       {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}{#4}[#5]}}
     {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}[fctaylor@#3]{#4}}}%
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{o}
   {\IfNoValueTF{##1}{\begin{fctaylor@#2}}{\begin{fctaylor@#2}[##1]}%
    \begin{fctayloritemize}\item[\thisthmhead\hfill]}
   {\end{fctayloritemize}\end{fctaylor@#2}}%
}

\theoremstyle{fctaylor}
\newfctaylortheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newfctaylortheorem*{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\section{One}

\begin{defn}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}\label{A}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Somebody]\label{B}
Something that should show how the text is split across line boundaries
and is correctly indented. And some equivalent conditions:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=(\alph*)]
\item a condition
\item another
\item and another
\end{enumerate}
which show the point made.

\indent\textbf{This line, which begins a new paragraph, should immediately follow the above line but be indented.}
\end{thm}

Here are the references: \ref{A} and \ref{B}.

\end{document}
```

**My work:** I tried mimicking [one answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42702/163955) to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42692/163955) as best I knew how by making the change from

```
\newtheoremstyle{fctaylor}% 
  {\topsep}%
  {\topsep}%
  {\normalfont}%
  {}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {}%
  {0pt}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {\makethmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

to

```
\newtheoremstyle{fctaylor}% 
  {\topsep}%
  {\topsep}%
  {\normalfont}%
  {}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {}%
  {\newline}%     The one thing I changed which seemed to work in the other answer
  {\makethmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish what I am seeking to do? (I just tried modifying the line in question by adding `\indent`, but this did nothing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re essentially putting your theorems/definitions in a `list` and displaying their headers as description items. The way you set up this format is seemingly convoluted, and I doubt this is the best way to achieve your goal.

But, based on your current code, what you need is simply `\listparindent`. However, I made some additional adjustments as well:

- There’s no need to use `\phantomsection`.
- I added `\relax` to `\itemindent=0pt`, just before the crucial line `\listparindent=\parindent`.
- I removed `\hfill` in `\item[\thisthmhead\hfill]`.
- Since I don’t fully understand your request about `\newline`, I added `\strut\par` immediately after `\item[\thisthmhead]`. This will cause the text after the header to be typeset in a new paragraph (and will make `\fctaylorlabelsep` useless, of course). If this isn’t what you want, simply remove `\strut\par`.

Again, I wonder if better code exists for your format.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{fctaylor}% name
  {\topsep}%      Space above
  {\topsep}%      Space below
  {\normalfont}%         Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {\makethmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\newlength\fctaylortheoremindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\fctaylortheoremindent{3em}} % <- customize here
\newlength\fctaylorlabelsep
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\fctaylorlabelsep{1em}} % <- customize here

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makethmhead}[3]{%
  \gdef\thisthmhead{%
    \makebox[\fctaylortheoremindent][l]{\bfseries#2}%
    {\bfseries#1}%
    \@ifnotempty{#3}{ (#3)}%
    \hspace{\fctaylorlabelsep}%
    %\phantomsection%%% THIS LINE ADDED% <-- This line commented out
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{fctayloritemize}
 {\list{}{%
    \leftmargin=\fctaylortheoremindent
    \labelwidth=\dimexpr\fctaylortheoremindent-\labelsep\relax
    \itemindent=0pt\relax% <-- \relax added
    \listparindent=\parindent% <-- What you missed
  }}
 {\endlist}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newfctaylortheorem}{smomo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\newtheorem*{fctaylor@#2}{#4}}
   {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
     {\IfNoValueTF{#5}
       {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}{#4}}
       {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}{#4}[#5]}}
     {\newtheorem{fctaylor@#2}[fctaylor@#3]{#4}}}%
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{o}
   {\IfNoValueTF{##1}{\begin{fctaylor@#2}}{\begin{fctaylor@#2}[##1]}%
    \begin{fctayloritemize}\item[\thisthmhead]\strut\par}% <-- \hfill removed.
   {\end{fctayloritemize}\end{fctaylor@#2}}%
}

\theoremstyle{fctaylor}
\newfctaylortheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newfctaylortheorem*{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\section{One}

\begin{defn}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}\label{A}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Somebody]\label{B}
Something that should show how the text is split across line boundaries
and is correctly indented. And some equivalent conditions:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=(\alph*)]
\item a condition
\item another
\item and another
\end{enumerate}
which show the point made.

\indent\textbf{This line, which begins a new paragraph, should immediately follow the above line but be indented.}
\end{thm}

Here are the references: \ref{A} and \ref{B}.

\end{document}
```

### With `\strut\par`

[image: With strut and par]

### Without `\strut\par`

[image: Without strut and par]

Comment: Thank you. I see my real issue was in dealing with how the `list` was defined. Adding `\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}` solved my concern about unwanted paragraph separation (I realize that was rather unclear by my question.) Also, `phantomsection` was added to make the hyperlinks work correctly. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442255/163955) showed why that was necessary. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Jessica I see. I hope the `\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}` is *global*. If so, for your nested list inside theorem, you may want `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\alph*)},ref=(\alph*),noitemsep]` or `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\alph*)},ref=(\alph*),nosep]`. Better yet, use `\setlist` to do it *globally* (see the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) manual for more details). Please note that you should use `\textup` instead of `\upshape`.